# Caffe | is there any Net which can be used to train rectangle shape images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have seen lenet, caffenet, cifarnet, alextnet and googlenet all networks require square shape images. In order to give rectangle shape images (per example I want to train person images) is there any famous net available?
Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.  The underlying problem is being able to standardize the filter shapes.  We chose simple squares as the *de facto* standard.  Actually, the more advanced nets do take arbitrary input, but adapt to it by taking square croppings from each image.

If you're so inclined, feel free to expand the various CNN layer routines to work with arbitrary rectangles, rather than a fixed square size.  Experience strongly suggests that taking a handful of cropped images from the original works as well, but look at how many times "experience" has been surpassed.

Comment: I already taking the cropped images of persons only.i actually reshaped them to 40*40 size and trained using lenet and cifarnet i got "90%" accuracy.Now i reshaped them 64*160 and trained them using lenet and cifarnet i didn't modify anything in both nets. I am getting nealy same accuracy of "90%".I want to improve those results ..Is there any way to improve results i mean adding convolutional layers or fully connected layers.

Comment: Yes, you can likely improve over 90%.  However, *what* will work depends a lot on the data set. For instance, applying GoogleNet to the MNIST data set will likely result in *serious* overfitting.  Since you haven't described your image set, I can't begin to suggest anything more specific than that you should go study the various features used in CNNs today and experiment with your data -- after all, that's how these models were developed in the first place.

Comment: Can you check this question once I explained about my dataset  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958451/caffe-how-to-improve-results-of-image-classification.